# C# ASP.NET MVC scripts being loaded in twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a C# ASP.NET MVC application that is loading scripts twice and giving me errors in the console. The first time the scripts are loaded, they are loaded correctly, but the second time, they are causing errors.

Here is a screenshot of the browser console:

[image]

Here is my layout, this is the only place where scripts are being called:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="png/favicon.png" id="favicon-i">

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/other")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/picker")
</head>
```

Here are my bundles, not all of them are being used:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

// Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. 
// Then, when you're ready for production, use the build tool at 
// https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/picker").Include(
                "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
                "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js",
                "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts").Include(
                "~/Scripts/tether.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/tether.js",                 
                "~/Scripts/apexcharts.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/layout.js",
                "~/Scripts/moment.js",
                "~/Scripts/Chart.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/other").Include(
                "~/Scripts/tether.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/tether.js",
                "~/Scripts/apexcharts.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/layout.js",
                "~/Scripts/moment.js",
                "~/Scripts/Chart.js"));
```

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                    "~/Content/layout.css",
                    "~/Content/Style.css",
                    "~/Content/tether.min.css",
                    "~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.css",
                    "~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css",
                    "~/Content/bootstrap-multiselect.css"));

Any ideas why this is happening?

EDIT: This is what the initiator looks like:

[image: initiator]

Comment: What is the difference between the files in `"~/Scripts"` and `"~/bundles/other"`

Comment: There is no difference, I was trying to see if `"~/Scripts"` was rendering everying

Comment: See this https://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2012/10/11/preventing-javascript-files-from-loading-multiple-times/  it may help if you use the script

Comment: Also, try to change `EnableEmbeddedjQuery` to be `false` https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/scriptmanager/disabling-the-embedded-jquery

Comment: I think that the directory change, So it gives an error 404.

Comment: You're packing the same scripts into different bundles, and you're rendering all the bundles in your layout file. Fix your bundles.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the initiator column on the network tab in Chrome dev tools can help track down where the files are being loaded from

[image]

Comment: It looks like every view is loading them in, could this be the case?

Comment: @GreenSaber Absolutely. If you are using partial views and there are script definitions in them they will be loaded once per partial view.

Comment: I'm using a layout that calls views. The scripts are being called from the layout which calls the correct view. I just checked again and the scripts are being called every time a view is called. How can I stop this?

Comment: @GreenSaber if you're calling an action to return the views return a PartialView instead of a View - the View call returns the layout with it whereas the PartialView only returns the .cshtml file

Comment: when I made the change my site only displayed the html of the partial view. No css, js, or anything from `_Layout`

Comment: @GreeenSaber you need to set in your partial view the LayoutFile